# Is a perfect Matching always a Maximum Matching?

Tags: graph-theory

Is a perfect Matching always a Maximum Matching ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, if you're using "maximum" in the sense of "maximum cardinality".  However, "maximum matching" might sometimes mean "maximum weighted matching", and  a perfect matching might not have maximum weight.